# Strange scp behaviour

Tags: copy, scp

I've got a script to scp a bunch of files to a server but am finding weird behaviour when i run the script on the server machine. The server machine is a mac running mavericks.

So if I scp a large file to the server from a different machine it's fine, but when I try and copy the same file from the server machine (using scp) it stalls constantly at around 2Mb transferred. Does anyone know why this would happen

Comment: SCP has no file limits, however the destination filesystem needs to support large files. What happens if you try to copy the file to the same machine using scp? (try with @localhost)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it must have been something to do with the network - I added the server name to the hosts file under 127.0.0.1 and the problem went away.